# PHP Script is not Automatically Sending Email

Tags: php

I have the following code at the top of a php error page:

`<?php
$message = "Your website has generated a 503 error";
mail('myaddress@mydomain.com', 'ALERT - 503 Error', $message);
?>`

Obviously the email address above is substituted with my actual email on the live site.

When I load the page, no email is sent. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Best to use a library that generates an error (*Like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)*). Also, have you tried actually sending the mail, with headers and all?

Comment: You should add headers `From:` like this:

    `$from = "info@yoursite.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    $message = "Your website has generated a 503 error";
    mail('yourmail@gmail.com', 'ALERT - 503 Error', $message, $headers);`

Comment: If the mail script still doesn't work when you add the headers argument, then you should open a support ticket and tell your hosting providers to allow the mail script for you on the server.